# Joey's and Chandler's coded telephone conversation

Tags: friends

In season 1 of *Friends*, during blackout, when Chandler was stuck in the ATM with a model named Jill, he tried to do some weird voice to let Monica know that he was stuck in the ATM with Jill Goodacre (I am not sure if I have written the surname correct!). When Monica was not able to understand him, he asked to put Joey on the phone and he understood what he said.

After that, Joey told Chandler to do something on which Chandler replied "Like that thought didn't pass my mind". What did Joey tell him?

Comment: We don't know, and that's the joke. It's up to the viewer to fill in the blanks.

Comment: I had a same question but if you heard it again you will find out that it was completely a sound, means that the writer consider this code speaking a 'jok'.

Comment: You're just at season 1. Keep watching and you'll get it eventually.

Answer (score 6):

Although I look forward to being corrected, I'm going to go out on a limb and say our lack of comprehension is quite literally "[the joke](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OrphanedPunchline)". The humour in the situation comes from that fact that we don't understand the (intentionally nonsensical) words that Joey says and the fact that Joey is mumbling in the first place, since Jill Goodacre can't hear him :-)

I think we can assume that his suggestion was something smutty or simply an admonition for Chandler not to blow his chances in getting a date with her.